# Trying to assign an array of items as property for a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create an array of objects and store it in the variable titled chats (temporary name for now) that holds objects with several properties: 'id', 'symptom', and 'diagnosis'. The 'id' and 'symptom' properties work perfectly, however, the 'diagnosis' property is having issues. I wanted to create a step by step list of instructions the app user would need to take to service a car. My first thought was to create an array of steps and assign that array to the 'diagnosis' property, but when run, the app displays the code as a single paragraph, instead of a bullet/ list. My second goal was to use ng-repeat to go through each diagnosis step for every object in the array, since the final array with have 60+ objects in it, each object having a different number of servicing steps as shown below.

```
<script>

<!-- An array of objects stored as an array in the variable chats -->
var chats = [{
    id: 0,
    symptom: 'WHEN THE CAR WILL NOT START/THERE IS NO POWER',

    <!-- For this diagnosis object property, the goal was to have some sort of list so I can ng-repeat through each step for every object in the chats array. I tried to create an array for this property but it didn't work as I intended -->

    diagnosis:
             [
             'Check the battery',
             'Make sure the battery terminals are clean',
             'Check the water level in the battery',
             'Check where the battery cable connects',
             'Check for blown fuses',
             'Make sure the battery is charged',
             'Check starter connections'
             ]
   },{
   id: 1,
   symptom: 'WHEN THERE IS A CLICKING SOUND',
   diagnosis:
            [
            'Check the items above',
            'Check the starter relay'
            ]
   }];

</script>

<html> <!-- Below is what is show on screen when the app is run on an    emulator -->

    ["Check the battery","Make sure the battery terminals are clean","Check the water level in the battery","Check where the battery cable connects","Check for blown fuses","Make sure the battery is charged","Check starter connections"]

</html>
```

Comment: The problem you pose in the title of this question actually works (comments omitted ofc). What's the exact question?

Comment: <!-- --> is not valid comment notation for javascript. It actually breaks javascript parser and makes browser output what follows to the page as html content.

Comment: ````/* valid comment for javascript not <!-- yatta --> */````

Comment: You should consider using const integer values to represent those actions instead of string values, especially when your array is growing fat. Storing array of string just for this purpose would lead to unnecessary  resource greed.